# what to do for a poorly explained question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've written a question on Stack Overflow. After reading the first two answers, I've realized that it was totally misunderstood, evidently because my description was very poor. 
Now I see two options:

1. make another question, even if I should leave the title unchanged, because I think the title was appropriate, or
2. edit the question to make it clearer, but so penalizing the two users who spent their time to answer and making their answers unfitting for the edited question.

What's the right thing to do?

Comment: It depends on how much will be changed. You will usually be better off creating a new question, especially if the answerers have put in a lot of effort. Do explain how the new question is different from the old one if they have similarities.